# PHP cURL timeout setting ignored

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I have a simple PHP script which tries to read the HTML data from a list of websites. It works fine, but with some sites that are very slow, or not online, my script dies as it times out MySQL.

```
        $ch = curl_init();      
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $page_to_hit);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);    
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10); 
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        $data =  curl_exec($ch);
```

Ideally I want this script to be done after 10 seconds max, and that cURL will show an error of some kind when I use curl_errno() in case that the URL went over 10 seconds.

Instead, PHP is totally ignoring these timeout settings, and it will hang for 60 seconds, by which time MySQL has had enough of it, and dies.

Why would PHP cURL be ignoring my timeout settings?

I tried running this script in the browser and also via command line. Both same results.

PHP Version 5.4.8
cURL Version 7.15.5

Comment: Do you have something that kills the script if your CURL call dies? Are you seeing if `$data` is false, for instance?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not actually timing out on 6 different websites?

Comment: Don't use `@`. Never. If you hide problem, it'll not disappear. It'll still be there and it'll more dangerous!

Comment: It seems part of the issue was: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, which is something I do need to use. The site that was giving me issues is 'http://dreamcatcher.asia'. Using http://www.rexswain.com/cgi-bin/httpview.cgi i was able to see that it redirects 5 times.. which is probably the issue. With CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION on false, my script worked. But still, with CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION on true, the TIMEOUT should work, which it doesn't. After 10 seconds, it is still pulling in data it seems, by which time it should have timed out, and given an error.